# Check Hyperlinks on post save

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Best workaround to build a script in Wordpress to change hyperlink structure on post save.

**Scenario:** an Author creates posts with hyperlinks `<a href="http://www.example.com"></a>` and saves, on save would be controlled if meets the hyperlinks given conditions to be redirected or not. If the urls has to be redirected than should change the structure of it `<a href="goto.html?url=http://www.example.com"></a>` and than push the post in database. What I want to avoid is to not force the Author to give attention on link creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add an action on [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook, and parse content to modify links (using a dom parser, or regexp).

But imo it is not a good idea to modify post content for this, you should modify links only when displaying post (with a [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter).

EDIT :

For example :

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content');
function my_content($content){
  ...
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: it sounds good what you suggest. This would mean that I have to build a function in my template structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can just sanitize the `href=""` values.

```
preg_replace('/<a(.*)href="([^"]*)"(.*)>/','<a$1href="goto.html?url=$2;"$3>', $postcontent);
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback and thanks for the codes, however I'm interested on the workaround: how do this(your codes) before the post is getting saved in the wp_posts table-> post_content

Comment: Hey. Don't save this way in the database. Preserve the user's content and just when displaying it, apply this. :)